# Android Firebase check if user close app or disconnects

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a full working multiplayer game (quiz). I have a timer for game (ends after e.x 90 seconds) and i have a retreat method (if the player press the back button he loose and scores 0).

My problem is if one of the two players close app (or even at reatreat) how to sent message that game is over and go to winning activity? I thing is usefull to show the game creation code:

```
private void initializeGameModel() {
        mGameModel = new GameModel();
        mGameModel.setId(mGameWaitModel.getId());
        mGameModel.setGameMaster(getPlayerModel(true));
        mGameModel.setGameSlave(getPlayerModel(false));
        mGameModel.setGenerateNewQuestion(true);
        mGameModel.setDidGameEnd(false);
        LOGD(TAG, "Game Model initialized");
    }
```

and firebase initialisation:

```
private void initializeFirebase() {
        mGameFirebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReferenceFromUrl(Constants.FIREBASE_BASE_URL + Constants.FIREBASE_TEST_PATH + Constants.FIREBASE_GAME_ACTIVE_PATH + mGameWaitModel.getId());
        mGameFirebase.setValue(mGameModel);
        mGameFirebase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                mGameModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(GameModel.class);
                if (mGameModel == null) {
                    return;
                }
                try {
                    if (mGameModel.isGenerateNewQuestion()) {
                        mGameModel.getGameMaster().setDidPlayerAnswer(false);
                        mGameModel.getGameMaster().setPlayerAnswerCorrect(false);
                        mGameModel.getGameSlave().setDidPlayerAnswer(false);
                        mGameModel.getGameSlave().setPlayerAnswerCorrect(false);


                    }
                    if (isGameMaster() && mGameModel.isGenerateNewQuestion()) {
                        generateNewQuestion();
                        mGameModel.setGenerateNewQuestion(false);
                        mGameFirebase.setValue(mGameModel);
                        return;
                    }
```

Actually what i need is when one of the two users retreat, close app (pressing the home button) game ends (for both users) and use the code for end game.

Thanks in advance for any help and effort!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onPause` or `onDestroy` function to set the DidGameEnd attribute to the true in the firebase. If you add a listener to the DidGameEnd attribute then if one of the users pause the app or exit from the app then you can notify the other user since you will change the attribute in other users app.

Comment: Kantarci I think your approach is the best. Is possible to give me an example as i m a little new to firebase?

Answer (score 0):

**You can manipulate by using:**

`onPause`, `onResume` (pressing home button),

`onClose` and `onDestroy` (to detect app destroy /close),

`onBackPressed` (two users retreat)